# igraph edges colored according to attribute disappear

Tags: r, colors, network-programming, igraph

I want to color in igraph the edges of a network according to another edge attribute.

Here it is what I have done:

```
vector <- c("a","b","b","d","b","c","c","a")
field <- c("friend","friend","good friend","archenemy")

g <- graph(vector, directed = FALSE)
E(g)$status <- field

library(RColorBrewer)
color = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = 
T)]
n <- length(unique(field))

col=sample(color, n)
sec=unique(field)
coloring <- as.list(setNames(col,sec))

E(g)$color <- coloring[E(g)$status]
```

Here I get an error, or no edges at all.

```
plot(g,edge.color=E(g)$color)
```

Comment: Don't use `as.list` with `coloring`. Just use `coloring <- setNames(col,sec)` and then you can just use `plot(g)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Your original code made a list of the colors in `g`. Check `E(g)$color`.

```
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)
color = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]

vector <- c("a","b","b","d","b","c","c","a")
field <- c("friend","friend","good friend","archenemy")
####
g <- graph(vector, directed = FALSE)
E(g)$status <- field

n <- length(unique(field))
col=sample(color, n)

coloring <- col[factor(field)]
E(g)$color <- coloring

plot(g)
```